# How to use aggregate functions with joins?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an main dataset(users) as follows.

```
ID  Username    Status
1   John        Active
2   Mike        Active
3   Ann         Deactive
4   Leta        Active
5   Lena        Active
6   Lara        Active
7   Mitch       Active
```

Further I have revenue table as follows.

```
subuser           hour          Revenue
John_01         2/26/2022 5:00     5
Mike_01         2/26/2022 7:00     8
Mike_02         2/26/2022 7:00     22
Leta_03         2/26/2022 7:00     67
Leta_07         2/26/2022 9:00     56
Mitch_07        2/26/2022 11:00    34
```

Now I need to get a table as follows.

```
User    Total Usage
John         5
Mike         22
Leta         123
Lena         0
Lara         0
Mitch        0
```

Here I need to get the sum of all hours of each user substring and match with main user table.Further if same hour is for same substring I need to get the maximum revenue value and other values should be neglect for that particular hour.

Ex:

```
Mike_01         2/26/2022 7:00     8
Mike_02         2/26/2022 7:00     22
```

Here `Mike_01          2/26/2022 7:00     8` should neglect.

So I tried as below.

```
SELECT
u.Username,
COALESCE(SUM(Revenue), 0) AS TOTAL USAGE
FROM users u
LEFT JOIN revenuetable e
ON SUBSTRING_INDEX(e.subuser, '_', 1) = u.Username AND
   e.Hour BETWEEN 'XXX' and 'XXX'
where u.Status='Active'    
GROUP BY
u.Username
order by u.ID.
```

But this didn't get the maximum value if same hour repeats. Can someone show me where I messed this?

update:
Do we have any method other tan using window functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If using MySQL that supports `row_number()` then join to a derived table that removes the unwanted rows.

```
SELECT
u.Username,
COALESCE(SUM(Revenue), 0) AS TOTAL USAGE
FROM users u
LEFT JOIN (
Select *
, row_number() OVER(partition by SUBSTRING_INDEX(e.subuser, '_', 1), hour order by revenue DESC) rn
From revenuetable ) e
ON SUBSTRING_INDEX(e.subuser, '_', 1) = u.Username AND rn = 1
   e.Hour BETWEEN 'XXX' and 'XXX'
where u.Status='Active'    
GROUP BY
u.Username
order by u.ID
```

Introducing this function and the `over clause` will give precedence to the highest revenue in each hour per user as the 'rn' column will be 1 for each such row.

Comment: I am running these query in a remote server and it do not support window functions. Do we have any alternative method?

Comment: You still need to filter out the unwanted rows before aggregating. Pity you had not stipulated the limitation in the question. I'm typing on a phone with one thumb so I'll let others take over now.

Comment: I updated the question. sorry for that. do we have any alternative?